# string concat causing 'str' object has no attribute 'object'

Tags: django

I have a view like below:

I get the error: 'str' object has no attribute 'object'

it must have something to do with my string concat - what has gone wrong :)

thanks

```
def edit_skill_plan(request):
    #t = skills.objects.get(skill_id='django_5158517')
    skillid = request.POST.get('editbut')
    user = request.user
    t = skills.objects.get(creator=user, skill_id=skillid)
    t.status = 'closed'
    t.save() # this will update only

    complete_date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    week_num = datetime.today().strftime('%V')
    x = t.skill_name
    user = request.user
    points = t.points
    cat = t.category
    year = datetime.today().strftime('%Y')


    status = str(request.user.username) +' completed the task: ' + str(x) + ' which was worth: ' + str(points) + ' points'

    status.object.create(creator=user, status=status, status_date=complete_date)
```

Comment: Is that the line that is causing the error?

Comment: It shows as this line actually! status.object.create(creator=user, status=status, status_date=complete_date)

Comment: You concatenate strings and save it to a varible named `status`.  Looking at the last line of your code I assume that you previously used an object or imported module called `status`. Just rename the string to e.g. `status_str` and it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last two line should be,

```
status_code = str(request.user.username) +' completed the task: ' + str(x) + ' which was worth: ' + str(points) + ' points'

status.object.create(creator=user, status=status_code, status_date=complete_date)
```